# Help I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Desktop beside windows XP

Tags: 14.04

Help I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop beside windows XP but I want to be sure whether the hardwares are supported (I think it is non-Pae)
My Desktop spec is:

```
CPU Type: Intel Celeron D 325, 2533 MHz (19 x 133)
Motherboard Name: MSI 865PE Neo2-PS (MS-6728 v2.0)  (5 PCI, 1 AGP, 4 DDR DIMM, Audio)
BIOS Type: AMI (09/29/04)
Display:
Video Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 4000 (Microsoft Corporation)  (128 MB)
Motherboard Properties:
      Manufacturer: MICRO-STAR INC.
      Product: MS-6728
      Version: 2.00
Rams: 2 * 512 MB = 1000 MB Memory Type: DDR SDRAM Memory Speed: PC3200 (200 MHz)
```

I need the best way to use if possible so not to lose Win xp
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advace

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu 14.04 will run? Check out Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: Dear  FuzzyToothpaste .. I think I will .. at the mean time I downloading linuxmint 13 xfce dvd 32 bit hoping it will run. Let me rewrite my question: is the specifications of my desktop suitable for such system! I could read too many problems concerning Non-Pae devices thats what I am woried about since I am very new outside MS-windows and I need to get out of it take my freedom with a good system.

Comment: The hardware looks old but common, which usually means at least reasonably good driver support. It'll probably be underpowered for Ubuntu's Unity desktop, so I recommend the derivatives [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which are better suited to low performance hardware..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Dysky,

You can run Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS without install it. During boot,the first question is if you want to install or run an instance to test it, then you can certify the compatibility of hardware before install it.

I hope that this procedure gives you the security required for a definitive installation.

kind regards and success!